# How configure TypeScript ESLint to infer void when it's no return is provided

Tags: eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

I just turn on TypeScript ESLint to our company project.

I wish to get warns or errors when a function DOES returns a value but inffer `void` when no return type is provided.

for instance:

```
function sum(a: number, b: number) { // SHOULD ERROR
   return a+b;
}
```

should warn about there is no return type (it should be number), and:

```
function doSomething(value:number) { // SHOULD NOT WARN
   doesNotReturns();
}
```

Its correct, because there is no returning value.

How can i configure estlinrc to achieve this behavior?

Comment: You didn't specify in your question - but I'm assuming you're talking about the `explicit-function-return-type` rule? This rule has no option to do this. What's wrong with typing out `: void` on these functions?

Answer (score -1):

First... in your rules add the new rule "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-types".
the rule has 3 options: off - no-error, 1-warnings, and 2- errors.

```
 "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": 1
 }
```

Comment: This does not answers the question